# Calculating the sum of values from a text file?

Tags: java, file, sum

im trying to find the sum of the cost of all my books in my libary system from a file, could someone say where im going wrong atm. It would be great help

```
int sum = 0;
    File Fileobject = new File ("E:\\text files for java\\BooksToImport.txt");


    try {
        Scanner fileReader  = new Scanner (Fileobject);

        // Read and display each line of the file

        while(fileReader.hasNext())
        {
            sum+= fileReader.nextInt ( );
            line = fileReader.nextLine();
            System.out.println(line);
            System.out.println(sum);
        }       
            fileReader.close();
```

This is my data im reading:

```
The_Hunger_Games - Suzanne_Collins - 5 - Scholastic_Press - 9781921988752

OOP_programming - Graham_Winter - 32.50 – Oreilly - 0471974555

Harry_potter - Jk_Rowling - 10 - Bloomsbury- 9788700631625
```

This is the errors im getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at c3500948JavaProjectAssignement1.c3500948.main(c3500948.java:80)
```

Comment: Could you add the first 5 lines of `BooksToImport.txt` and any error or exception you are getting?

Comment: That depends how your txt is written, nextInt() will return a number, and nextLine will return a String of a whole row

Comment: I think the issue is that you *think* the scanner will skip text to the next int when using nextInt() but that's not true. Doc here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: if you have the comman structure throughout the text file then you can iterate in loop for file rows reading all line and then splitting the each line with - symbol and then assuming you price is at position 3 parse it and use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Asumming your file has fixed format Text (no other words has - as seperator) and position for amount value** here is something you can try:

text file :

```
book1- author1- 100 - press1- 978846521988752
book2 - author2 - 100 - press2 - 9788928465887521
book3 - author3 - 100 - press3 - 9784659219887521
book4 - author4 - 100 - press4 - 9788928465887521
book5 - author5 - 100 - press5 - 9784659219887521
book6 - author6- 100 - press 6- 9788984659887521
```

TestClass.java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
class TestClass
{
    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception
    {
        FileReader file = new FileReader("test.txt");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
        double sum = 0;
        while(sc.hasNext())
        {
            String line = sc.nextLine();
            // spit the line on - char
            String [] data = line.split("-");
            // Important : assuming price is always at index 2 parse and use value
             sum = sum + Double.parseDouble(data[2].trim());   
        }
        sc.close();
        System.out.println("Sum is "+sum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first line of your file is:

The_Hunger_Games - Suzanne_Collins - 5 - Scholastic_Press - 9781921988752

The code

```
sum+= fileReader.nextInt ( );
```

expects a number thought.
Before calculating the sum you need to parse out the part of the line which is the number to be added to the sum.

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast responses it's very much appreciated. Im living this community atm :)

Answer (score 0):

[Scanner.next*()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) reads a stream until the next delimiter (the default is defined in [Character.isWhitespace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace(char))).  When you call `nextInt()` it reads the next delimiter and then attempts to parse it as an `int`, if it is not then you get an InputMixmatchException.  You can define your own delimiter like this (using an escaped regegex for `<space>-<space>`):

```
new Scanner(input).useDelimiter("\\s-\\s");
```

Then you would need to call `.next()` to skip over the parts of each line that you aren't parsing.

Now that last line of your example shows a hyphen directly following the publisher (without space).  This fix might require more work over more data (such as book titles with hyphens in them).  Hopefully, this gets you unstuck.